# unpack to int and string in python

Tags: python, variable-assignment, iterable-unpacking, shorthand, python-typing

Is there a way to unpack to diferent types? this is the case:

```
# data = [4, "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
(parts, *words) = data
```

`data` is provided. I never assign this value. I add as example.
`parts` must be an int, all the rest of the list is assigned as list of strings.

The only way that I have found is reassign the variable `parts` as next:

```
(parts, *words) = [4, "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
parts = int(parts)
```

but I don't like repeat asignment variable twice in a row. Since python is a language that keeps clean and simple I'm looking a solution.

*edit:
Let me know if is a valid practice reassign twice in a row.

Comment: In the list - `data` , if the first element(number) was int.  Then variable `parts` would be int and you would not need to change it to type "int".   Can you please provide more info on what you are expecting ?

Comment: not necessarily, the source could be reading a file and be a list of strings, where the first string is a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python's static typing annotations, `list`s (and all sequences aside from `tuple`s) are assumed to be of homogeneous type (which may still be a union of multiple types, but it's not a different single type depending on which index you're looking at). Your `list` is violating that assumption by having index `0` have one type, while the other indices have a different type. Even though Python in general doesn't enforce the "intended" usage of `list`, type checkers do, and there's no mechanism to work around that shy of manual casts or type conversions, as you're doing here.

Short answer: **You're "misusing" `list`s, and `typing` won't help you when you do that.** So either ignore/disable the type-checker for this code (it'll work just fine after all), or live with a pointless cast.

Comment: assuming it was a homogeneous list of strings, the first element would be a number encoded as a string. 
I don't think it would violate the principle of the list. The 'data' is from an unknown source such as a stdin.

Comment: @iLevi: Yes, but in that case the parse to `int` would be necessary, not an optional add-on to satisfy the type-checker. If the question is "Can I one-line the unpack and conversion?" the answer is "Not in any clean way that takes advantage of unpacking the way you're trying to do it". You can always do junk like `parts, words = int(data.pop(0)), data` or `parts, words = int(data[0]), data[1:]`, but you're repeating yourself *somewhere*, and it's all uglier/more confusing than the two-liner you came up with.

Comment: Your answer seems to me reasonable and valid. I will see if there is no other comment on it and if there is no other opinion I will mark it as a response. Thank you, my friend.

Answer (score -1):

How about this? It tests each item for type and puts it into the proper list as needed.

```
data = [4, "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
parts = []
words = []
[parts.append(item) if type(item) == int else words.append(item) for item in data]
```